# How many bitcoins are there currently in circulation?

Tags: money-supply

Where do I find the total number of bitcoins currently out there?

Answer (score 14):

If you are running Bitcoin Core, you can see the total amount in circulation using the RPC call `gettxoutsetinfo` (in the Bitcoin-Qt debug console, or using bitcoin-cli if you run bitcoind).

At the time of writing, the output is: 
`{
  "height": 517245,
  ...
  "total_amount": 16965398.58586455
}`

which means there are currently ~17 million BTC in circulation. This number takes into account certain types of destroyed coins.

See also [this answer of mine](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38994/will-there-be-21-million-bitcoins-eventually/38998#38998) about how many there will eventually be.

Answer (score 2):

The number of bitcoins currently in circulation can be found at [BlockChain.info](https://blockchain.info/charts/total-bitcoins) or [BitcoinCharts.com](http://bitcoincharts.com/bitcoin/)

### Background

The rate at which new bitcoins are mined follows a predefined schedule, with a new block appearing roughly every 10 minutes. The amount of bitcoins in a newly mined block started as 50 and gets halved every 210,000 blocks.

There can be at most [20999999.9769 BTC](//bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/9962/1489), so nearly 21 million bitcoins.

Answer (score 1):

> Fun Fact:

In fact, there are only 21 million Bitcoins that can be mined in total. Once miners have unlocked this many Bitcoins, the planet's supply will essentially be tapped out, unless Bitcoin's protocol is changed to allow for a larger supply.

> Where do I find the total number of bitcoins currently out there?

https://bitcoincharts.com is a good place where you can find it.

The number in circulation at the moment is 16.523M

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because it almost exclusively repeats information from other answers and gives an outdated answer to the asker's main question: More than 16.96M Bitcoins are already in circulation.