# Can someone explain this weird mining activity?

Tags: empty-blocks, block-validity

I can't figure why this block has 0 coinbase with 0 transactions... however still a valid block? Or it it empty? According to whalepanda this coinbase was sacrificed by unknown miner.

See the block at [height
    501,726](https://btc.com/0000000000000000004b27f9ee7ba33d6f048f684aaeb0eea4befd80f1701126)

Answer (score 13):

It has no transactions other than the coinbase transaction. However, the transaction's coinbase output is 0 BTC. Here's the valuable piece of information that you are looking for:

> Coinbase outputs **may** be set lower than the max. value (12.5 currently), and the block will be valid (if the difficulty is lower than the target, as always)

Also look at: https://btc.com/0000000000004c78956f8643262f3622acf22486b120421f893c0553702ba7b5

BTW, the miner loses money, for the price of being "cool".

Comment: i dont see anything special about this block https://btc.com/0000000000004c78956f8643262f3622acf22486b120421f893c0553702ba7b5

Comment: also why this block has more than 50 btc in coinbase output? 124,725
block -https://btc.com/0000000000006a01cb8932bc8a90b79297c744d4e5a355312208ab558b1e89a5

Comment: @anacondabitch: The coinbase transaction output can be, at most, the sum of the block reward *plus* the total of all transaction fees of other transactions in the block.  So this block had BTC 0.13 in transaction fees.  btc.com appears to display coinbase transactions in a confusing way; if you look at other block explorers (e.g. https://blockchain.info/block-index/139575/0000000000006a01cb8932bc8a90b79297c744d4e5a355312208ab558b1e89a5) it is more clear what is happening.

Comment: @NateEldredge lol looks like https://btc.com/0000000000004c78956f8643262f3622acf22486b120421f893c0553702ba7b5 lost -12.50000000 BTC in Fees .... i dont see any tx how does that happen?

Comment: @anacondabitch: You're misreading it.  This block had a total of 8 transactions.  One was the coinbase, seven had no fees, and the eighth had a fee of BTC 0.01.  So the coinbase was allowed to be up to BTC 50.01.  The miner chose to claim 49.99999999 instead, effectively destroying the remaining BTC 0.01000001.

Comment: @anacondabitch: I think the issue is that btc.com takes the value of the coinbase c;aimed, subtracts the block reward, and displays the result as "fees".  In the normal case, the maximum coinbase is claimed, which is in fact reward plus fees, so this number does equal the fees.  When the maximum coinbase is not claimed, this number can look funny or negative and doesn't accurately reflect the fees in the block.

Comment: Is this equivalent to burning bitcoin, or does it mean that there is more bitcoin available to be mined in a future block?

Comment: @SteveEllis Yes, they're equivalent. They've lost ~$150k.

Answer (score 4):

Block contains "RSKBLOCK:Ý¿QzßýKÊwQP[9É:
ÔyüN9ÝW³GÆ$", so I think that it is related to www.rsk.co. Probably Sidechains synchronization.

EDIT:
Binary hex: "52534b424c4f434b3addbf517adf8ffd4bca7751505b39c9013a0d1fd479fc4e901b39dd57b347c624"
Source: https://blockchain.info/tx/9bf8853b3a823bbfa1e54017ae11a9e1f4d08a854dcce9f24e08114f2c921182?show_adv=true

Comment: what is that scary string?looks like some extraterrestrial code RSKBLOCK:Ý¿QzßýKÊwQP[9É: ÔyüN9ÝW³GÆ$

Comment: That string is not meant to be converted to text. Rather it is just binary for a RSK block hash. When converted to text, it looks to be a weird string.

Comment: @AndrewChow Well, the first 9 characters seem to be meaningful in text.

Comment: How did you converted hex: "52534b424c4f434b3addbf517adf8ffd4bca7751505b39c9013a0d1fd479fc4e901b39dd57b347c624" into ASCII ... any idea?

Comment: @anacondabitch try to search "hex to ASCII" on Google