# Verifying Block 124724

Tags: blockchain, mining-reward, consensus, verification

Just for my own educational purposes, I'm writing something that verifies the blocks on the blockchain. I had in my code this line:

`assert coinbase_amount == block_reward + total_tip`

And it succeeded until it hit block [124724](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/0000000000004c78956f8643262f3622acf22486b120421f893c0553702ba7b5?page=1), at which point it said coinbase_amount was 49.99999999 BTC and that the block_reward + total_tip was 50.01 BTC. (So, it complained that 49.99999999 != 50.01)

I guess if that's true, it's fine, since the miner I guess just dropped .01000001 on the floor. I'm just wondering if I'm interpreting that block right. (And how often does this happen?? And why??)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `assert coinbase_amount == block_reward + total_tip`

That's not correct. The actual consensus rule would be `coinbase_amount <= block_reward + total_tip` (in other words: miners are allowed to burn funds).

> I guess if that's true, it's fine, since the miner I guess just dropped .01000001 on the floor.

Correct.

> I'm just wondering if I'm interpreting that block right.

Indeed, that's exactly what happened.

> And how often does this happen?? And why??

Due to buggy miner software, generally. The case in block 124724 was later explained by its presumed author (see [this post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=7253.msg184414#msg184414)), though there are around 1000 other instances later, collectively burning around 19 BTC. I have some more information about these and other cases of burnt coins in [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/38998/208).